# In PHP how do you echo the 2nd key of an array from a function?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to output an array key which get returned from a function.  Currently its like this:

```
$x = explode('/', 'my/path/home');
echo $x[1];
```

but how can i output with just one line without the variable assignment?

I'm trying this, but it doesnt work:

```
echo explode('/', 'my/path/home')[1];
```

Comment: Array dereferencing was added in version 5.4.

Comment: In PHP 5.4, you can use the 2nd example, but in < 5.4, you need to stick with the 1st.

Comment: Also, don't forget to do some basic bounds checking on the array. Trying to access the key at index 1 of explode('/', 'foobar') would result in an error.

Comment: The real question is: why do you want it to be a one lines so badly?

Comment: i want to keep it as simple as possible and it looks better one the eyes with just 1 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* do this in one line, IMO it is preferable to use `list`:

```
list(, $x) = explode('/', $path);
```

This is arguably better than the long-winded

```
$x = implode('', array_slice(explode('/', $path), 1, 1));
```

in which it's easy to forget what you were supposed to be doing in the first place.

If you are not sure if there *will* be a second element, you can guard against problems with

```
list(, $x) = array_pad(explode('/', $path), 2, null);
```

However, I don't really recommend any of the above for real code. Use the two-liner if you have to; it will still be easier to read than any of these solutions.

Comment: Well, that's a one liner for the assignement of $x, but you still need two lines to output $x.

Comment: @FrédéricClausset: All of these solutions are really just thought exercises. The best would be either PHP 5.4 array dereferencing or else two lines without any of this "cleverness".

Comment: OK, I agree with you about all this "cleverness". Maybe we could devise a true one-liner using regex and eval.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried but this may help you:

```
echo array_slice(explode('/', 'my/path/home'), 1, 1);
```

Also, this code would explode if there's no slash in the string.

Comment: Actually you will need an extra `implode` around this to turn the one-element array back into a string. Which means that this is possible with clever use of array functions, but it's not a good way to write real code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a one liner for wathever the reason and your PHP version < 5.4, you could just create a function for that :

```
function getPath($fullPath) {
   $x = explode('/', $fullPath);
   return $x[1];
}

//now the one-liner
echo getPath('my/path/home');
```